# After upgrading xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 ----->no gpsd? no xgps!

Tags: networking, gps, viewports

I am trying for days to get my GPSD working with my very sensitve Handy-GPS.

No problem to get the NMEA Data via rfcomm0 from my handy-GPS.

```
gpsmon /dev/rfcomm0 works perfect
```

But no chance to deal with XGPS since I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04.

```
 systemctl status gpsd.service

● gpsd.service - GPS (Global Positioning System) Daemon

 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gpsd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

 Active: activating (start) since Sat 2021-03-06 10:15:47 CET; 1min 10s ago

 TriggeredBy: ● gpsd.socket 

 Cntrl PID: 3417 (gpsd)

 Tasks: 1 (limit: 18994)
 Memory: 1.4M
 CGroup: /system.slice/gpsd.service
         └─3417 /usr/sbin/gpsd -n -N -D4


    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:PROG: shmat() for SHM export succeeded, segment 65558
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:INFO: running with effective group ID 20
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:INFO: running with effective user ID 121
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]:   gpsd:INFO: startup at 2021-03-06T09:15:47.000Z (1615022147)
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:CLIENT: => client(0):
    {"class":"VERSION","release":"3.20","rev":"3.20","proto_major":>
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:PROG: checking client(0)
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:CLIENT: <= client(0): ?WATCH=
     {"enable":true,"json":true,"scaled":true}\x0a
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:CLIENT: => client(0): {"class":"DEVICES","devices":           []}\x0d\x0a{"class":"WATCH","enabl>
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:PROG: checking client(0)
    OMEN-17cbxxxx gpsd[3417]: gpsd:INFO: detaching 127.0.0.1 (sub 0, fd 8) in detach_client
```

With

```
netstat -ptaun
```

I can see the standart port 2947 for GPSD is blocked!?

No idea what this line means??

```
 tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2947          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init
```

Starting my GPSD like

```
sudo gpsd -n -N -G 2948 /dev/rfcomm0
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv4 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: can't bind to IPv6 port gpsd, Address already in use
gpsd:ERROR: maybe gpsd is already running!
gpsd:ERROR: command sockets creation failed, netlib errors -1, -1
```

My questions:

What stand that 1/init for ?

How can I swing over my GPSD port?

```
@heynnema

cat /etc/default/gpsd

# Devices gpsd should collect to at boot time.

# They need to be read/writeable, either by user gpsd or the group  
  dialout.
  DEVICES=""

# Other options you want to pass to gpsd
 GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -N -D4 "
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gpsd-clients gpsd` to fix problem?

Comment: If `gpsmon` "works perfect" (which means that it starts, and then shows NMEA/location data), then gpsd is running and working properly. If `xgps` is not working, start it from a command prompt so you can see it's error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gpsd.service is disabled. Enable it and start it...

`sudo systemctl enable gpsd.service`

`sudo systemctl start gpsd.service`

`sudo systemctl start gpsd.socket`

`sudo systemctl status gpsd*`

**Update #1:**

Reverted /etc/default/gpsd back to default file by purging and reinstalling gpsd.

**Update #2:**

You may need to edit /etc/default/gpsd and change the following lines...

START_DAEMON="true"

DEVICES="/dev/rfcomm0"

**Update #3:**

Make sure that port 2947 is open in your firewall. Then xgps and cgps should work.

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120542/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-after-upgrading-xubuntu-18-04-to-20-04-no) which is more suitable for extended discussion.